# Using boost::threadpool with boost::bind hangs my program in an infinite loop

Tags: c++, boost, bind, threadpool, raytracing

I'm trying to parallelise a certain aspect of my program using `boost::threadpool` (not an official part of `boost`, [link](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)). However, I am finding my program stalls and upon inspection, `htop` shows me that there are two inactive threads (I suspect in my threadpool) and one thread running at 100% (I suspect my main execution thread).

Here is the relevant code:

```
namespace rt {

class Renderer
{
  public:
    Renderer(int threads) : tp(threads) {}

    void render(const Scene&, const Camera&, Image&) const;

  private:
    mutable boost::threadpool::pool tp;
    //int tp;

    static void render(const Scene&, const Camera&, Image&, int, int);
    static Color trace_ray(const Ray&, const Scene&, int depth = 0);
};

} // namespace rt
```

```
void
Renderer::render(const Scene& scene, const Camera& cam, Image& image) const
{
    for (int y = 0; y < image.get_height(); ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < image.get_width(); ++x)
            tp.schedule(boost::bind(&Renderer::render, scene, cam, image, x, y));

    tp.wait();
}

void
Renderer::render(const Scene& scene, const Camera& cam, Image& image, int x, int y)
{
    Color c = trace_ray(cam.spawn_ray(x + .25f, y + .25f), scene)
            + trace_ray(cam.spawn_ray(x + .75f, y + .25f), scene)
            + trace_ray(cam.spawn_ray(x + .25f, y + .75f), scene)
            + trace_ray(cam.spawn_ray(x + .75f, y + .75f), scene);

    image.set_pixel(x, y, c / 4.0f);
}
```

The reason I suspect the problem lies with my `boost::bind` construct is that when I create a `void foobar() {}` function and pass that to `boost::threadpool::pool::schedule`, the program does not get into it's infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with boost bind or thread pool and not your code? It sounds like you have synchronization issues that result in a live lock.

Comment: This might also be possible, I just rewrote my code to use `asio::io_service` instead of `boost::threadpool`, and the same error persists. However, I have no clue where it might lock. As you can see in the lower `render` function, all the function does is trace some independent rays and set a value in image (which is basically just a big array). Since each thread only accesses a different element in the array, and only writes, I don't see how it could result in a live lock... That's why I think I am probably using `boost::bind` wrong.

Comment: Also, another thing: When I only have one thread in the threadpool, it still hangs. So this doesn't look like a concurrency problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments given to `boost::bind` [will be copied](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

> The arguments that bind takes are
>   copied and held internally by the
>   returned function object. For example,
>   in the following code:
>
> int i = 5;
>
> bind(f, i, _1); a copy of the value of
>   i is stored into the function object.
>   boost::ref and boost::cref can be used
>   to make the function object store a
>   reference to an object, rather than a
>   copy.

In your case:

```
tp.schedule(boost::bind(&Renderer::render, scene, cam, image, x, y));
```

will send copies of `cam`, `image`, `x`, and `y` to `Rendered::render`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: excellent point, boost::ref should be used at least for the scene and possibly the camera and image as well.

Comment: This was it! I send a reference to image so that it sets the pixel on my actual image object instead of the copy, and references to scene and cam for optimisation purposes. I'm guessing the default copy constructor was somehow entering an infinite loop for one of the objects, or was failing in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using boost::thread_group as impromptu thread pool instead?  What is the implementation of wait() being used here the name would imply a barrier which could be why your threads are becoming inactive indefinitely.

Edit:

Can you call render without going into an infinite loop?  Perhaps it is in the way you are tracing or spawning rays which is not shown.  Also it looks like you may want to call `wait_for_all_tasks` on your thread pool based on a brief glimpse at the link you posted to it's implementation.

Comment: I should have added that in the original post, when I don't use any kind of multithreading, but just run everything on the main execution thread, it works fine, and I get pretty pictures. The problem does not lie in my rendering algorithm, multithreading is something I am trying to fit in now that I know the basic things work.

Comment: depending on the implementation of your functions you may need to add a critical section for any thread access to shared objects like your scene.